# python interpreter: interrupt and continue

Tags: python, windows, debugging, interpreter

After I interrupt execution in Python interpreter (using CTRL-BREAK in Windows), can I continue execution?

If not, is there any other way to interactively pause execution (so I can view variable values), and then continue?

I prefer not to use the debugger because it's much slower than normal execution.

Comment: Do you mean, pause execution of any running Python process, attach a debugger, monkey around, and then detach and let it continue?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I was hoping it could be done by running a Python program from the Python interactive shell, pressing CTRL-BREAK, and then doing some magic to continue. But any other way to achieve the same outcome would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some useful links that kinda answer my question:

http://blog.devork.be/2009/07/how-to-bring-running-python-program.html

[How do I attach a remote debugger to a Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543196/how-do-i-attach-a-remote-debugger-to-a-python-process)

http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

[Is there a way to attach a debugger to a multi-threaded Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701/is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-debugger-to-a-multi-threaded-python-process)

Overall, it seems winpdb can do what I need (I'm under Windows), but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you mean `pdb` by `debugger`, but if you don't (and it might be helpful for others here), you can try:

- http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Here's a nice tutorial btw:

- http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/09/01/debugger.html