# While using two threads in Python when an error occurs the program does nothing, why?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I'm making a simple server for my game in Python and I'm using two threads. One thread is looking for new users that wish to connect (for  it shall be a MMORPG!) and the other is communicating with users. My problem is this: I can't debug! Or at least, it's very hard because when an error occurs nothing happens! Lets say I write "pint" instead of "print" (which I did, as a test) I would normally get informed and the program would terminate. Now I don't even get informed nor does the program quit. Nothing, and this is making it extremely difficult to locate where errors occur.

I tried using 'ctr+C' but it does nothing, even then the program wont exit, I have to shut down the terminal!

Why is this happening and how can I fix it (or am I doomed)?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701/is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-debugger-to-a-multi-threaded-python-process and the answers over there - maybe that solves your issue.

Comment: You're going to need to post some code (or a lot more detail). "When an error occurs" is not specific enough. What kind of error? A wrong user command? An actual typo in your code? What? Does Ctrl-Break work when Ctrl-C fails? (If that last is true, you most likely have a simple thread deadlock on your hands)

Comment: I'll second the request for more detail.  However, I'm betting that in one or both of your network threads you've got a try/except catchall that is catching your typo exceptions and also catching CTRL+C (KeyboardInterrupt).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reason of your problem, but I think you can solve with this:

```
import sys
...
print >> sys.stderr, 'whatever you want to print'
```

I use a function for this Debug information with coloured output (DEBUG is a global variable):

```
def debug(self, *txt):
    if DEBUG:
        print >> sys.stderr, '\033[31m[Debug]:\033[0m ', ' '.join([str(e) for e in txt])
```

Comment: I'll see but I don't think that this is the solution to my problem, I can always just normally print. Maybe I'm guessing wrong, because I do not know the purpose of this, could you explain what should this do?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd read that you can't print in standard output (very quick reading, it's my fault). Anyway, you can raise exceptions in each important operation and debug your program